# How to download file over ssh tunneling in GO

Tags: go, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to find a way to make a connection to a server over `ssh tunneling` and download a file. But no matter what I try, there is no way I get it to work.

I'm running this code on `Windows10`

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/sgreben/sshtunnel"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)


    func main() {
    keyPath := "sshtest2_private.pem"
    authConfig := sshtunnel.ConfigAuth{
            Keys: []sshtunnel.KeySource{{Path: &keyPath}},
        }
    sshAuthMethods, _ := authConfig.Methods()
    clientConfig := ssh.ClientConfig{
            User:            "some_user",
            Auth:            sshAuthMethods,
            HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        }
    tunnelConfig := sshtunnel.Config{
            SSHAddr:   "xx.xxx.xxx.xx:22",
            SSHClient: &clientConfig,
        }
    conn, _, err := sshtunnel.Dial("tcp", "zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz:22", &tunnelConfig)
    if err != nil {
    panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(conn, "GET /")
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, conn)
    }
```

And when I try to connect I get this error:

```
panic: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

For the authentication I use the sshtest2_private.pem file which is in the same dir as my main.go which looks something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

the content of my key

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Don't know why it's complaining about the public key and don't know how to fix this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you exec `scp` in terminal shell without password ?

Comment: yes I can run it without password.

Comment: why not  use `exec.Command("scp", src, dest)` ?

Answer (score 0):

SSH server allows public key authentication only for those keys that are listed in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`

1. Create the public key for `sshtest2_private.pem`

   ```
   ssk-keygen -f sshtest2_private.pem -y
   ```

   This command prints the public key to stdout.
2. Append this public key to `xx.xxx.xxx.xx:22`, file `/home/some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`
   If the file doesn't exist, create it. Access rights must be user-only (`chmod 600 /home/some_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

I tested, it works.

BTW. Your tunnel's endpoint is `zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz:22` but you use it for `GET /`. Looks like its port should be `:80`, not `:22`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to say that I'm on windows. I have a `.ssh` folder in my users directory and there I just have a `known_hosts file`. I added the `authorized_keys` file and pasted the private key after running your command but still getting the same error. I think I had to add the ip to the key so in the end my file looks something like this: 
`xx.xxx.xxx.xx:22 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA...........`
I also tried it without an IP and with and without port but still no success :(

Comment: @DevMan `authorized_keys` should be on server not on your client machine.

Comment: @bogdanoff they already are. I can connect to the server with for example `WinSCP` through tunneling from my windows where I use a `.ppk` file, which contains both the public and private keys. But I can't connect with this code.

Comment: @DevMan can you login to `xx.xxx.xxx.xx`? What is the result of the command `ssh some_user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx -i sshtest2_private.pem`? If no, copy `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA...` to `authorized_keys` on **xx.xxx.xxx.xx** machine, not your local workstation

Comment: @PakUula When I use the command, I get this error: `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`

Comment: @DevMan That's the answer - you are not allowed to the server that you try to tunnel through

Comment: @PakUula That's weird. I can use the same private and public keys on the same PC to tunnel to the server with WinSCP software. I'm missing something.